# How to read a CSV value, calculate the increases and then find the max value

Tags: python, pandas

I need to read a CSV file, and be able to divide the variables between each other in order to receive percentages.
The CSV file is in the format

Date & time | Usage

so for example

02/08/20 16:02:00 | 1432

03/08/20 17:02:00 | 1440

04/08/20 15:02:00 | 1445

so for example id want to divide 1440  by 1432 to give 1.0055 and 1445 by 1440 to give 1.00347 and then find the max value (1.0055) printing both.

This is about as far as ive gotten

```
import pandas as pd

A = pd.read_csv("Test4.csv")
```

Thank you for any and all help and your time.

Comment: is what your dividing by always the previous line? so you would expect 2 possibilities given the 3 choices posted?

Comment: Yes, so the three points you get 2 answers, for 4 we get 3

Answer (score 1):

And now

```
A.Usage.pct_change.max() + 1
```

Comment: thats awesome i had no idea about `pct_change`  I like it when I learn new things

Comment: @IgorRivin my apologies understand now. Thank you!